# Way to connect test points on circuit board when both sides of board must be accessible?

Tags: pcb, 7segmentdisplay, testing

I have a commercially made circuit board with multiple 7-segment displays (HSP-H103) soldered into it. I need to test the displays to make sure all of the segments work for each one.

The problem is that it is difficult to hold wires or leads against the necessary test points which still being able to view the display.

I thought of maybe trying to use a mirror, but getting the mirror at the right angle is not easy.

Is there any easy way to hole a lead to a solder point on the back of a circuit board?

Comment: You can't use a pogo-pin board with the display wired out of that?

Comment: @RonBeyer I didn't even know pogo pins existed. That's why I asked the question. I suppose I could solder some pogo pins to a perf board to make a layout that would test the displays. It would be a significant amount of work to do this, but it is probably better than trying to hold the test leads by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Ron's suggestion of pogo boards can be  used. There are cupped head ones that are designed to connect to through-hole pins. Photo from [here](https://elmwoodelectronics.ca/products/pogo-pins-cupped-head-10-pack?variant=24126865795&currency=CAD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&utm_campaign=gs-2019-02-19&utm_source=google&utm_medium=smart_campaign&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-a3fi4bx6gIVYQiICR2pwg3ZEAQYBCABEgLJJvD_BwE):

[image]

Those particular displays have a duplicate common pin on both top and bottom rows, so you could make a little hand-held tester with 5 pogo pins that is held by hand on the display being tested.

---

Usually to test a display like that, a test program in the driver is used, which avoids the necessity to add extra connections, tests the driver and tests the PCB for opens at the same time.